# In a loop How to set a value if even one record passes check

Tags: sql, oracle

I am joining two tables `Employee` and `Wages`. Now an employee can have multiple wages as they can be working in different projects and I want the sum of his wages.There is also a column called `Employee_benefits_Claimed_Ind`. This is an indicator that indicates if the employee claimed any benefits in each project. He can claim benefits for some projects and not claim for some but as far as I am concerned if he claims benefits on even one project he does not qualify. Here is the table I am trying to populate:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_QUAL
(Employee_id NUMBER,
 TOTAL_WAGES NUMBER,
EMPLOYEE_disQUALIFY CHAR(1))


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_QUAL(Employee_id, Total_wages, EMployee_disQualify)
SELECT      c_Employee_id,
            c_Total_wages,
            c_Employee_disQualify
FROM        (
                Select  Employee_ID as c_Employee_id
                from    Employees
            ) e
LEFT JOIN   (
                Select      SUM(Wages),
                            Employee_disQualify
                from        wages
                group by    Employee_disQualify
            ) w on e.employee_id = w.employee_id
```

However if an employee claims benefits for one and does not for another this will just have two entries because of the `GROUP BY`. Ideally it should only be one entry with the Employee_disqualify_ind as 'Y' since he claimed benefits on one project. It does not matter if he did not on the other one. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Where is `Employee_benefits_Claimed_Ind` in this query?  Is that supposed to be the same as `EMPLOYEE_disQUALIFY`?  And the same as the `Employee_disqualify_ind` you mention in the sentence "Ideally it should only be one entry with the Employee_disqualify_ind as 'Y'"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess at what you're really saying.

In English:  For all employees as specified by `Employees.Employee_ID`, sum up wages on the `WAGES` table, and set `EMployee_disQualify' = 'Y' if any of the`wages.Employee_disqualify` flags are set to Yes.

In SQL, That would be:

```
SELECT e.Employee_ID,
       sum(w.wages),
       case when 
          (sum (case w.Employee_disQualify WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 else 0 end)) > 0
              THEN 'Y'
              ELSE 'N'
       end
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN wages w 
   on e.employee_id = w.employee_id
group by e.employee_ID
```

(where I've just shown the select).

The main trick is to convert the employee_disqualify flag into something numeric (using `CASE`) so it can be easily aggregated, and then covert the result of this aggregation back to a Y or a N w/ another `CASE`.  If there is at least one Y in any of matching rows, then the sum will be > 1, so, you'll get a Y as your final result.  Otherwise, N.  (And again, I'm guessing as to how your field is set.)

If you weren't aggregating, I'd might do it with an in-line `select 'Y' where exists . .` type cluase, but you're already aggregating anyway for `sum(wages)` and this gets calculated on the same scan through the `wages` table, so this should be reasonably efficient.

For example, see here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67691/2

Comment: Interesting sqlfiddle I knew just the jsfiddle :)

Comment: The guy who wrote it is on here -- @Jake Feasel  I found it here myself and use it all the time.